# Mount: "The disk drive for UUID=<uuid for /> is not ready yet or not present."

Tags: upgrade, fstab

I recently did the update from 12.04 to 12.10 on my old Dell Latitude CPx laptop (Pentium III). When I rebooted I got this error message with no response from keyboard input. Below it is says

```
Wait to continue, press S to skip mounting, or M for manual recovery.
```

I also see occasional errors pop up on the screen from mountall and Plymouth. 
I can still get into Recovery Mode. Can anyone shed some light on the matter?

Update: I redid my fstab, to no avail. Now my screen is flashing on and off from the Ubuntu 12.10 splash screen to a black screen. I would really love to avoid a reinstall...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the UUIDs of some of your partitions have changed. And your /etc/fstab specifies the old UUID so it is not able to mount / and some other partitions during boot process.

If you have a Ubuntu 12.10 desktop CD (Live), boot from it, open a Terminal

Run `blkid` to get the list of UUIDs for all your block devices/logical volumes.

Then mount your `/`, for example if your root partition is on `/dev/sda2` and type is `ext4`

```
cd /mnt
mkdir root
mount -t ext4 /dev/sda2 /mnt/root
nano /mnt/root/etc/fstab
```

Make sure the UUIDs of partitions/block devices are correct, if not, update and save.

**NOTE**: if you don't like UUID, just use traditional block device, e.g. /dev/sda2 instead of UUID=x

Then run

```
sync; sync; cd /mnt; umount /dev/sda2; reboot
```

You should be back on track.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The error message is gone but now my screen is flashing on and off from the Ubuntu 12.10 boot splash screen and a black screen.

Comment: This could be video driver issue. Anyway, you can disable the boot splash and see the output by commenting out the following line in /etc/default/grub: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quiet", don't forget to run update-grub to reflect the change. The output during boot should be of some help.

Comment: This happens from time to time with me. It has nothing to do with partitions being changed.